Using Custom Authentication Header to validate Webhook event notification endpoint URL
Folks,
I have implemented a cloud run service on GCP that execute a task when it receives specific webhook events from Zoom.
I implemented this on my GCP personal instance where i allowed invocations to the service for All users "--allow-unauthenticated" and this works fine and i can receive the webhook notifications with no issues.
I am implementing the same cloud run service on Corp instance, and because this follows IAM restrictions, i assigned the proper roles and generated an access token for the service account that will be used to invoke this cloud service. I validated the jwt token generated for this service account using https://jwt.io/ and i see that it is verified with(header, payload, and signature) and identifies correctly the payload parameters as seen below
{
  "aud": "https://<my_service>-uc.a.run.app",
  "azp": "project-service-account@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email": "project-service-account@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "exp": 1713376412,
  "iat": 1713372812,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "103391207022993207898"
}

In order to Validate the endpoint URL on Zoom , i can only put https://<my_service>-uc.a.run.app/webhook and i have the option to add custom authentication header.
The issue is that when i use this custom Authentication Header option to validate the cloud run service URL, I am forced to use the custom key that starts with X- so per Google docs i use the custom-header key as X-Serverless-Authorization and put the token value in the Custom-header value, this token is stripped to allow only 477 chacareras while the actual token has 1342 characters so i can not validate the cloud run service URL.
How can i resolve this issue?
I tested the token using Postman and it works and the cloud service is invoked properly.
On the cloud run logs i see the error 401 below
httpRequest: {
latency: "0s"
protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
remoteIp: "134.224.xxx.xxx"
requestMethod: "POST"
requestSize: "878"
requestUrl: "https://<my_service>-27yx5cwkda-uc.a.run.app/webhook"
serverIp: "216.239.xxx.xxx"
status: 401
userAgent: "Zoom Marketplace/1.0a"
}
insertId: "662057d4000922aea554a953"
logName: "projects/<my_project>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-04-17T23:14:28.608925342Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "WARNING"
spanId: "8093509743174912171"
textPayload: "The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#401"
timestamp: "2024-04-17T23:14:28.588093Z"
trace: "projects/<my_project>/traces/6e5e28f3fb239c761dfecd4ea683cb00"
traceSampled: true
}

